# Laravel, how to add on the fly condition to query with query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, union, query-builder

This is the problem:

How to add condition like limit or offset to a query before a union condition was made?

This is what i tried:

```
$query = DB::table('table_name');
$query->where(condition);
$query->orWhere(condition);

$query_no_union_yet = $query->select(field list);

$query->union(another_table);
$result_without_limit = $query->get();

$query_with_limit = $query_no_union_yet->limit(10);
$query_with_limit->union(another_table);
$result_with_limit = $query_with_limit->get();
```

The real code is very long and complicated but this is the situation.
When reach the row `$query_with_limit->union(another_table);` I add a union to the one I've made before, and this is not what i want. I have to be able to add limit at the first query only after it gave me results, and gain in this way 2 sets of results.

It's possible, Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [clone the object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) so you have two query builders which are two separate instances.

```
$query_no_union_yet = (clone) $query->select(field list);
```